# Scaling a change to cf-query across large project

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a large application with a few thousand different cf-query tags so need a solution that scales easily. I have recently ran into the problem where we need to gather the run time of all the queries in a .cfc. I would like the query time to be saved to `Request.queryTime` and have tried to make a custom tag that looks like this.

```
<cfquery name="the_query" datasource="#Attributes.datasource#" result="thisResult">
    #thisTag.GeneratedContent#
</cfquery>
<cfset Request.queryTime = Request.queryTime + thisResult.ExecutionTime />
<cfset Caller['#Attributes.name'] = Duplicate('the_query') />
```

When I replaced cfquery with this new custom tag it worked for some queries but ones that contain

```
<cfqueryparam>
```

return the following error.

`Context validation error for tag cfqueryparam. The tag must be nested inside a cfquery tag.`

I have also looked into making a funcion that adds

```
Request.queryTime = Request.queryTime + queryName.ExecutionTime
```

but this unfortunately needs to know the query name and will require adding the name to the function for all the queries.

If anyone has any suggestions that would much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the Slowest Queries report in the ColdFusion Monitor is not good enough?

Comment: Unfortunately the time we want is the sum of all the queries in a .cfc and we also want that sum to be saved to our database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself a cf_query and cf_queryparam custom tag set. The cf_queryparam should remember the data for its attributes and then output a unique marker. Then your closing cf_query tag can turn that back into a cfquery with cfqueryparam tags, track the run time, and return the result.

The key is to use cfassociate in cf_queryparam to make the data available to cf_query.

I have a custom tag set that does all of this (except the time tracking piece, but it looks like you have solved that problem already) on a private repo, but I can post it up somewhere accessible if that would help.

In mine, I create an array and each key is either a string of SQL or a struct representing a cfqueryparam. Then it is really easy to loop through that array inside a cfquery tag. In my testing so far, this is actually very fast.

Once you have it done, a global find/replace for cfquery to cf_query done in a single commit should get you up and running.

Comment: Yea that would be very helpful If I could see your example. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/sebtools/Neptune/tree/Development/CustomTags

You will need to look at DMQuery.cfm, DMParam.cfm, and DMUdf.cfm (where most of the real work is done).

Then look at the "runSQLArray" method of: https://github.com/sebtools/Neptune/blob/Development/CustomTags/com/sebtools/_DataMgr.cfc

Let me know if you need help!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would say if you want data calls to scale, if you're using inline queries, especially those whose `select` columns or `where` statements change conditionally, you're better off converting them to stored procedures. Do not use dynamic SQL, figure out the variations of a single query and write a proc per variation. Also, write separate procs for `insert`, `update` and `delete`, then use the application code to determine which to call instead of making that decision inside the proc.

Secondly, I don't think this approach is going to give you the date you want in the way you envision. You might be better using a testing framework like [TestBox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/testbox) to call the queries individually or grouped as needed and record process time. This is something you could then run under a load testing tool like [jMeter](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/7/25/web-site-testing-with-jmeter) to see how it performs under concurrent requests.

Finally, if you want to see how your code and queries are running in various environments or production, take a look at [Fusion Reactor](https://www.fusion-reactor.com/). This will give you insight to bottlenecks, including the parameters being sent to slow running queries. It saves a history of the data it collects, so you can compare them as code changes.